# Angular calendar: adding links to events

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using the angular calendar package in my app and I use it to display the tasks and events that other people have posted in the group. I fetch the task and event posts from the backend and then display them in the calendar. I was wondering if I could add a link to these events? I want to take my user to the actual task route when they click on the items.

**I clicked on the date and a list appears, when I click the items on the list I want to go to the route where they show the actual task**

[image]

**I've added a link to the event object, but now I don't know how to add this property to the events in the templates**

[image]

**the template**

```
<div class="container">
  <br />
<div class="row text-center">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        mwlCalendarPreviousView
        [view]="view"
        [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
        (viewDateChange)="changeDate($event, 'previous')">
        Previous
      </div>
      <div
        class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
        mwlCalendarToday
        [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
        (viewDateChange)="activeDayIsOpen = false">
        Today
      </div>
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        mwlCalendarNextView
        [view]="view"
        [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
        (viewDateChange)="changeDate($event, 'next')">
        Next
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <h3><b>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en' }}</b></h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="view = 'month'"
        [class.active]="view === 'month'">
        Month
      </div>
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="view = 'week'"
        [class.active]="view === 'week'">
        Week
      </div>
      <div
        class="btn btn-primary"
        (click)="view = 'day'"
        [class.active]="view === 'day'">
        Day
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div [ngSwitch]="view">
  <mwl-calendar-month-view
    *ngSwitchCase="'month'"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [refresh]="refresh"
    [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
    (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)">
  </mwl-calendar-month-view>
  <mwl-calendar-week-view
    *ngSwitchCase="'week'"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [refresh]="refresh">
  </mwl-calendar-week-view>
  <mwl-calendar-day-view
    *ngSwitchCase="'day'"
    [viewDate]="viewDate"
    [events]="events"
    [refresh]="refresh">
  </mwl-calendar-day-view>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I missed this (eventClicked) that my colleague added. I can simply add a router function in that method.